# Django ImageFile _get_image_dimensions() returns None

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using django's ImageFile to execute the following commands:

```
>>> f = open("path/image.jpg")
>>> myImage = ImageFile(f)
>>> dim = myImage._get_image_dimensions()
>>> dim

>>> dim is None
True
```

There is no error message shown but dim is empty and the type is 'NoneType'.

```
>> myImage.height
```

is returning error message because of it:

```
File "some\path\django\core\files\images.py", line 21, in _get_height
    return self._get_image_dimensions()[1]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I am running python 2.7, django 1.6 on a windows 7 machine, My friend tried the same code on the Mac and it works fine.

Comment: Just to double check: `dim is None` or some other NoneType?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4965a774074780f3e4858bcc975476f71edf2c2c/django/core/files/images.py#L53). You'll see that `get_image_dimensions` reads a chunk from the file and tries to parse it into an image with PIL. If it fails, it increases the chunksize and repeats. (Increasing the chunksize is to read the whole file in less reads than (filesize/initial chunksize) times. [Fileformats like TIFF need to read the while file.](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11155))

Returning `None` may happen in 3 cases.

1. An empty file. And the [first chunk read is empty](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4965a774074780f3e4858bcc975476f71edf2c2c/django/core/files/images.py#L55).
2. After reading the whole file, PIL can still not parse it into a file. Is your file complete? Is it an image?
3. If Pillow sets the size to `None`. Try using PIL directly on you machine and see it can parse your file.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the insights. However in my case **1,2** The image can be opened and displayed fine by any image viewer on windows. I assume its not empty and it's complete.               
**3.** In PIL, `myImage.size` gives the right answer.
     `Image.open("path\image.jpg").size`  returns `(50, 50)`

Comment: And `p = PIL.ImageFile.Parser().feed(open("path\image.jpg").read(1024)); p.image.size == (50, 50)` too?

Comment: Thank you for following up!  `ImageFile.Parfeed(open("path\image.jpg").read(1024))` returns error message: `File "some\path\PIL\ImageFile.py" . in line 361, in feed` - `self.data = self.data + data` - `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'file' and 'str'`